# How to check radio button selection value to match array item

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I'm making my own lorem ipsum generator and am trying to match my radio input value to the array value so that when it's `true`, it will generate text based on the array value.

For example, since one of the radio has the property `value="harry"` and my array in my generator.js file has a `harry` variable in the `characters array`. It will generate text from the `harry` file.

My code so far

```
// index.html
<form name="form" action="/" method="POST">
    <div id="charType">
      <label class="btn btn-warning char harry">
        <input name="charType" type="radio" value="harry">Harry
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-warning char ron">
        <input name="charType" type="radio" value="ron">Ron
      </label>
    </div>

    <input type="number" class="paragraph-number" name="numberOfParagraphs">
    <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="generate-button">
  </form>

  <div class="generated-text">
    <div class="placeholder-div"></div>
  </div>
```

and my generator.js

```
const harry = require("./harryText");
const ron = require("./ronText");

const loremIpsum = new GenerateNewText();
function GenerateNewText(){
  characters = [
    harry,
    ron
  ]
}
```

This is the code that works but doesn't incorporate the radio selection feature and requires my having to hard code which variable within the array to access.

```
GenerateNewText.prototype.getRandomSentence = function() {
   let randomSentence = harry[Math.floor(Math.random() * harry.length)]
   return randomSentence;
}
```

Obviously, I do not want to hardcode `harry` and I want to let `randomSentence` generates text based the selected radio input.

So I tried manipulating the code to this, among many other variations

```
GenerateNewText.prototype.getRandomSentence = function() {
  document.getElementsByName("charType").is("checked", function() {
      var selection = this.val();
      while(character < characters.length) {
        if(selection === characters[i]) {
          let randomSentence = [Math.floor(Math.random() * harry.length)]
          return randomSentence;
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

but I can't run it because document is not defined. I know the code block directly above is a mess but I don't know how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in :

`if(selection === characters[i])`

`'selection' is a string while 'characters[i]'` is not.Instead use a characters object something like this:

`characters ={'harry':harray, 'ron':ron}`

and compare selection with the keys of characters

`if(characters[selection]){}`

It's difficult to debug your code.. here is another suggestion :
-use `document.getElementByClass` instead of `document.getElementsByName`